# Find Related Class jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, target

I have four links, inside of primary-nav, which need to activate a corresponding slideDown element. The links have separate parent classes, `.patient > a`, `.doctor > a`, `.primary > a` and `.locations > a`.

When someone clicks on `.patient > a` I need ul.patient to be the ul that is targeted.

I am kind of experimenting, but this is what I have thus far:

```
var $patientDrop = $('ul.patient');

$patientDrop.hide();
$('.patient > a').click(function() {
  if ($patientDrop.is(':visible')) {
      $patientDrop.slideUp(function() {
        $('.patient > a').removeClass('active');
      });
  }
  else {
    $patientDrop.slideUp(function() {
        $('.patient > a').removeClass('active');
    });
    $patientDrop.slideDown();
    $('.patient > a').addClass('active');
  }
});
$('body').click(function(event) {
if (!$(event.target).is('a')) {
  $patientDrop.slideUp(function() {
        $('.patient > a').removeClass('active');
  });
}
});
```

Now, im using variables just for learning, and perhaps they are what is needed here. But my real question, is how to go about this in the most efficient way. I'd hate to have to repeat all of this code four times with different variables just to have it work with each four of the links and their corresponding UL's.

Is their any way to, say: `primary-nav a, get class of clicked a, find ul with this class` And then run the rest of the script?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DRZZr/

Comment: The corresponding HTML and a http://jsfiddle.net demo would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're talking about `.patient > a`, but there are no `<a>`s that are children of `<ul class="patient">`.

Comment: I have updated my jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/DRZZr/2/ maybe that clarifies it a bit. Each of the top links needs to open the list below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the anchor isn't inside the `ul.patient` that you want to expand, I would use a `rel` attribute or something similar to know what your target is.  jquery ui does this a lot in its data targets. See my updated jsfiddle for an example:

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/DRZZr/7/ UPdated JSFiddle script given new requests/requirements.

I also added some ids to make targeting easier.  I used ids for elements that were "static" -- that is, they have real meaning and aren't used for just common styling.

The meat of the change is this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#primary-nav li').click(function()
                                 {
                                     var $elem = $('#sliderareas > ul.' + $(this).attr('rel'));
                                     var $this = $(this);

                                     if($elem.is(':visible'))
                                     {
                                         $elem.slideUp(function() {
                                              $this.find('a').removeClass('active');
                                          });
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                         $elem.slideUp(function() {
                                            $this.find('a').removeClass('active');
                                          });

                                        $elem.slideDown();
                                        $this.find('a').addClass('active');
                                     }

                                 });
});
```

Hide all #sliderareas uls, and then show the one with the class similar to the `rel` of the li that was clicked.  You could also put the rel on the anchor inside the li, or use the href='#hash' of the anchor if you prefer, then onclick of the `a` use the `href` attr to find a #sliderareas ul with id set to `$(this).attr('href')`.  If you need that example I can make another jsfiddle edit.

Comment: It worked great, but once I transitioned it into my own code it broke. Can you lend some guidance? http://jsfiddle.net/U9WrC/

Comment: Modified.  SEe new JSFiddle for expansion to more closely match your example.  Now each drop down functions independently so you can have all of them expanded at the same time if you want (similar to the way your setup works).  Each click toggles the state of expansion of its appropriate "companion" section.

Comment: I have updated my code, and it all works great: http://jsfiddle.net/DRZZr/6/

Except, is it possible to slide all other open elements up when one is activated? I thought my script did this already, but apparently, as you can see in the jsFiddle, it does not.

Comment: My original script did this. I thought you wanted them to be left expanding.  See http://jsfiddle.net/DRZZr/7/ for an updated script, including body click.  Updating my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var myClass = $(this).parent('li').attr("class");
    var $patientDrop = $('ul.' + myClass);
    alert(myClass);
    // Your code...
});
```

​

Comment: Is there a way to get this working with four total dropdowns? Updates jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DRZZr/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the parent ul, then you can use jquery's parent method.

```
$('.doctor  a').parent('ul')
```

will target the parent ul.

Comment: The ul isn't a child of the ul.primary-nav unfortunately.